# Why is my page ignoring the rest of the content after an include?

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to use includes to create a page header based on whether or not the user is logged in, but although the proper header appears, the remainder of the page content does not.

```
<div class="header">
<?php 
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn()) {
    include("views/logged_in.php");
    exit;
} else {
    include("views/not_loggedin.php");
    exit;
}
?>
</div>

//Rest of page content goes here
```

If I put this code *after* the page content, it shows up basically like a footer and everything *works* fine, but doesn't look the way I want.

Comment: Because you declare `exit;`!  from the docs [exit — Output a message and terminate the current script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

Comment: why is my code doing EXACTLY what i have coded it to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is the calls you have made to the exit() function, this function is an alias of the php die() function which stops any further output to the browser, causing the bottom of the file to not be processed.

If you get rid of the exit function calls after the includes, then the page below should render as normal.

You may have been thrown off by the closing  tag being rendered in the browser, the php won't be processing this, but most modern browsers are smart enough to realise the closing tag is missing and place it there for you.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the exit was keeping it from falling through, but I guess that'd only apply if I was using it with case, not an if/else.

Comment: Correct, with switch statements you can use 'break;' to prevent cases from falling through.

Answer (score 0):

remove exit

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn()) {
 include("views/logged_in.php");
} else {
include("views/not_loggedin.php");
}
?>
```